# Странное имя сайта при миграции вопроса на enSO

Tags: дефект, локализация, перенос-вопросов

Был вопрос, который [перенесли на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52559707) и там под вопросом висит такая надпись:

> [image: this question came from site for программистов]

Надпись «this question came from site for программистов» выглядит странной.

Можно было бы написать что-то типа, этот вопрос пришел из части нашей сети и дальше имя сайта, или вопрос перемещен с "имя сайта".

Заведён баг-репорт на MSE: [Problem with translations at moved question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316223)

Comment: Ошибка в том, что слово на русском языке затесалось в предложение на английском? Ну, это криво реализованная интернационализация. Названия сайтов ложатся в шаблон `site for %name%`, шаблон переводится как попало.

Comment: С этим лучше на Метамету приходить. Подозреваю, что @alexolut уже либо сам написал об этом, либо видел такой вопрос. Так что ждём его. :)

Comment: что такое метамета? первый раз такое слышу если честно)

Comment: Это Мета всей сети. Вот, я нашёл этот вопрос: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286603/296059 Там эта проблема в двух других местах была и она там уже решена. Сможете новый вопрос там завести со ссылкой на этот?

Comment: сейчас попробую)) а что если у меня не получится? что тогда делать?

Comment: А как оно может не получиться?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316223/problem-with-translations-at-moved-question

Comment: Как бы Вы хотели, чтобы выглядела надпись?

Comment: упс ) интересный вопрос, но я не уверен что мое мнение на что-то повлияет)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko почему же? Хорошие идеи не пропадут зря.

Comment: ну можно написать что-то типа, этот вопрос пришел из части нашей сети и дальше имя сайта, или вопрос перемещен с "имя сайта"